# jQuery not showing/hiding different ID search element after clicking button

Tags: jquery, html

I got the following issue that is driving me mad. I'm trying to show/hide a Search form by clicking on the search button to open it, and again to close it. Now, opening the form is working as intended, but upon clicking the icon again, it's not closing. I'm not working with the jQuery show() and hide() function and prefer to keep it that way.

My jQuery is:

```
$( 'span#search-button' ).click( function() {
    $( 'span#search-button' ).prop( 'id', 'search-button--active' );
    $( '#drawer-search-form' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
});


// broken bit, what it should do is effectively revert to the hidden state we changed in the previous code, but needless to say it won't.
$( 'span#search-button--active' ).click( function() { 
    $( 'span#search-button--active' ).prop( 'id', 'search-button' );
    $( '#drawer-search-form' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
});
```

This is the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="drawer-heading">
  <!-- the starting state of the search form is hidden -->
  <div id="drawer-search-form" class="drawer-search-form-style hidden">
    <!--<?php get_search_form(); ?>-->
  </div>
  <div class="drawer-search-button">
     <a href="#search-open">

       <!-- the button that opens and supposedly closes the search form -->
       <span id="search-button" class="fa fa-search fa-border-circle fa-border-circle-fill fa-border-circle-float fa-border-circle-large" aria-hidden="true">
       </span>

      </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now what I have tried is changing the selector to anything I could think of. I have also tried using `event.preventDefault();` to check if something else was messing with it but to no avail. I've also tried using `attr` instead of `prop`, and changing the entire structure of the code to something different.

I've been roaming SO for solutions but nothing suggested in other threads works on my code, sadly.

Frankly, it does nothing it should do as specified in the second jQuery block. Which made me think this was a selector issue; but I literally tried everything I could think of to fix the selector... Help would be very, very much appreciated.

To summarize:
I have a button that opens the search form. This works. But when attempting to *close* the form by pressing that button again, it does *not* hide the element again.

Comment: as your button with that id doesn't exist to start with, that second click won't be bound at the time it is called - either do a [delagated bind](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) or do an if and check for the id in your original button click and change what the button does, depending on it's id

Comment: Hello Pete, thanks for the pointer! I'll dive into the documentation you linked and have a go at that! Thanks!

Comment: Added an answer to explain the different options you can do with examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your button with id `search-button--active` doesn't exist when you bind your click event, the event is never bound therefore your click doesn't work.

In order to get over this, you need to [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) like so:

```
// original selector must be something that is there when the binding occurs
$('.drawer-heading').on('click', 'span#search-button--active', function() { 
  $( 'span#search-button--active' ).prop( 'id', 'search-button' );
  $( '#drawer-search-form' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
});
```

However as you are binding to a button and then changing the ID (I would recommend against changing the id), I would just change your original code so instead of changing the id, you add a class and then do all your logic in the same button bind:

```js
$( 'span#search-button' ).click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#drawer-search-form').toggleClass('hidden');  // as you just seem to be adding and removing a class, you can use toggleClass
});
```

In the above, you toggle the class on the target div, and also on the button so any active style for the button can be targeted using `#search-button.active`

If you were doing something more complex than just toggling a class, I would have done it like this:

```
$( 'span#search-button' ).click( function() {
    var button = $(this);

    if (button.hasClass('active')) {
        button.removeClass('active');
        $('#drawer-search-form').addClass('hidden');
        // do other stuff too
    } else {
        button.addClass('active');
        $('#drawer-search-form').removeClass('hidden');
        // do other stuff too
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explenation and the solution Pete! I was unaware of _toggle_ and have implemented your solution and it works perfectly. Interesting how binding works, I'll set some time aside to learn more about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the id of the button and use `toggleClass` functionality to add or remove the class `hidden`.

```
$( '#search-button' ).click( function() {

$( '#drawer-search-form' ).toggleClass( 'hidden' );
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You toggle it with if else . I don`t understand why you are giving to id another ID . It will not work , but you can toggle it with class

```
$( 'span#search-button' ).click( function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('search-button--active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('search-button--active');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('search-button--active'); 
  }});
```

This is my solution .

Comment: Of course you can use toggleClass function but in my version you can add more functionality for click

Comment: Hello Giorgi, thank you so much for your answer. I was unaware of the existance of the toggle function and decided to implement that (as suggested by Pete earlier). I do understand your solution allows for much more functionality, and I'll analyze it thoroughly! Thanks!